# Ordered list of integer vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

For a given length $n$ and a maximum positive integer value $N$, I'd like to generate a list that contains all $n$-vectors with entries between $-N$ and $N$ (of which there are $(2N+1)^n$. Further, the list should be sorted in such a way that first the element with all zeroes appears, then the elements with a single non-zero entry, then two non-zero entries, and so on. How the elements are ordered within a block with a specific amount of non-zero entries is unimportant.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Generally, people here appreciate if questions show a minimum level of effort on the askers part. To get you started, take a look at [`Range`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html), [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html), [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) and [`Count`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html).

Comment: You surely mean $(2N+1)^n$ not $n^{2N+1}$?

Comment: @yarchik indeed, thanks, editied

Comment: @LukasLang I'm stuck in the stage of confusion. I will look at the functions you mention

Comment: Try to sort `Table[IntegerDigits[i, k, n] - ConstantArray[1, n], {i, 0, k^n - 1}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to LukasLang:

```
ReverseSortBy[Tuples[Range[-nmax, nmax], n], Count[#, 0] &]
```

does the job. Here `nmax` = $N$ from the question.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I had in mind. One minor improvement: You can write `Count[0]` instead of `Count[#, 0]&` (this is the third usage form in the documentation of `Count`)